# Convert iso-8859-1 hex escape sequence to lowercase

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have a string like this:

```
$str = "\xC4";
```

According to wikipedia the `C4` is ISO-8859-1 Hexcode for `Ä`. Now i want to lowercase this string to get `ä` (also in ISO-8859-1).

I tried various solutions using `strtolower` and `mb_strtolower`. None of them worked. The output was garbled every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the encoding in [`mb_strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php), so just specify it and it all works fine:

```
echo mb_strtolower($str, "ISO-8859-1");
                        //^^^^^^^^^^
```

output:

```
ä
```

Answer (score 1):

`strtolower("\xC4")` works just fine. The thing is that you need to interpret the resulting byte (`xE4`) using the ISO-8859-1 encoding, otherwise you'll obviously see garbage. If you're doing this in a browser, set the appropriate header to clue the browser in to the expected encoding:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
echo strtolower("\xC4");
```

Comment: thank you deceze, btw just 10 min ago i started reading your article about charsets etc. great read!

Comment: I'm sorry tho that your solution didn't work, the strtolower didnt actually lowercase it. Rizier123 solution worked though.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it's locale dependent. Worked locally for me, but may indeed not work elsewhere. An explicit encoding-aware mb function is indeed better suited for the task.